# change image of button in custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I want to change the image of button on custom cell,given code changing the image on double click.I want to change image on single click(check and uncheck)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

        SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        } 
        NSString *localArrayData = [LocalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text =localArrayData;
        cell.CheckButton.tag=indexPath.row;
        [cell.CheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkU.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.CheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckButtonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        return cell;
    }
- (void)CheckButtonAction:(id)sender
    {
        NSInteger row = [sender tag];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        SimpleTableCell *cell = [DataTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if(appDelegate.didSelect)
        {
            [cell.CheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkU.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            appDelegate.didSelect = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.CheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            appDelegate.didSelect = TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: consider clarifying the question with more detail. That will help SO users to help you. As it stands it includes a large section of code with no comments or explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
-(void)selectUser:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *) sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
    CustomTableViewCell *tappedCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
    if ([tappedCell.selectButton.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"]])
    {
        [tappedCell.selectButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [tappedCell.selectButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you will set cell's  indexPath as button tag

```
cell.selectButton.tag=indexPath.row;
```

and set selector to button

```
[cell.selectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectUser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

inside UIButton Action write this

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
if (btn.tag==0)

{
    btn.tag = 1;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else
{
    btn.tag=0;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: how to solve this error         -Property 'tag' not found on object of type '_strong id'

Comment: still have a problem,first cell change image  on double click,remeing cell working properly