# Change images in dynamic radio buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios7

[image]in table view cell i am creating the radio buttons dynamically.if i click one button,then i want to change the remaining buttons as disable

```
 -(void)RadioButton:(UIButton *)Sender
 {
     int i=Sender.tag;
 }
```

in this Method i am able to change clicked button image only.

Comment: how can i change the another buttons images,from one button

Comment: @SanketBhavsar   did you work on the dynamic ui?

Comment: radio button is present in all the cells?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32862434/3883040 this might help you..

Comment: @user6April its not at all work for me.

Comment: You must show screenshot of UI.

Comment: @user6April please check that link.actually we dont have an idea how many radio buttons are in view,which is taking from server data.

Comment: how can i add the screenshot

Comment: capture a screenshot ,edit your question and click on button exact right on code formatting button

Comment: @user6April,Please check this is table view,in table view cell multiple radio buttons are there.

Comment: there are two radio buttons in each cell ?

Comment: for this two only is there,it may change to 3 also.by dynamically how we can manage this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102466/discussion-between-mahesh-reddy-and-user6april).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to update radio button in all the cells, you will have to reload table view once button is tapped to reflect so in all cells. You can try out following code

```
 NSInteger selectedButtonIndex = -1;
 -(void)RadioButton:(UIButton *)Sender
 {
     selectedButtonIndex=Sender.superview.tag;
     // reload table view
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //create your table view cell..

    if selectedButtonIndex == -1 {
         //set button state for no button selected
    }
    else if selectedButtonIndex == indexPath.row {
         //enable button
    }
    else {
        //disable button
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry its not help full to me.i cannot reload the table once click on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would use UITableView reload API for this problem (*reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:* or *reloadSections:withRowAnimation:*). Just set the enable state of all buttons in *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* and modify your model information about these states before reloading parts of the table. Try to avoid *reloadData*.

For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
cell.button.enable = yourModel.canDoSomething;
...
}


-(void)radioButtonDidChange:(UIButton *)Sender
{
    yourModel.canDoSomething = NO;
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<indexPaths> withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```